# why is it important to find stability of supergravity solutions?

Tags: string-theory, supergravity

I want to know about the importance of the stability,
generally,why is stability important in super-gravity?
and why do we like these solutions?

Comment: i think the answer is to accomodate the estimated age of the universe, only stable solutions could presumably do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(expand my comment as an answer)

First, in supergravity theories (e.g the Kaluza-Klein type) the vacua solutions may be infinite or many.

This immediately poses a problem for a physical theory which needs some uniqueness properties.

Then the property of **stable vacua** (aka stable solutions) is used as a condition for selecting among the possible soluions for the ground state of the theory. (for example a reference on [Kaluza-Klein supergravity](http://www.aei.mpg.de/~theisen/DNP.pdf), section 5.2)

When a vacuum state is not **stable** it is refrerred as [**metastable** (as in thermodynamics) or **false vacuum**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum). This is a local minimum but not the lowest energy state, even though it may remain stable for some time. As such it is meta-stable and can revert to the lowest energy state at some time.

From wikipedia article on stable vacua and relation to cosmology:

> For decades, scientific models of our universe have included the
>   possibility that it exists as a long-lived, but not completely stable,
>   sector of space, which could potentially at some time be destroyed
>   upon 'toppling' into a more stable vacuum state. The
>   Standard Model of particle physics opens the possibility of
>   calculating from the masses of the Higgs boson and the top quark,
>   whether the universe's present electroweak vacuum state is likely to
>   be stable or merely long-lived.
>
> ...This catastrophic bubble of "true vacuum" (per quantum models)
>   could theoretically occur at any time or place in the universe, which
>   means (because the bubble of "true vacuum" will expand at the speed of
>   light) the end of such a false vacuum could occur at any time.